# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" en JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
function addToTable(title, year, type, poster, id) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML += `
        <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td><a href="${poster}">${title}</a></td>
            <td>${id}</td>
            <td style="text-transform: capitalize">${type}</td>
            <td>${year}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="moreInfo(${title})">Click Here</button></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>`;
}

function moreInfo (name) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = `         
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Rated</th>
        <th scope="col">Released</th>
        <th scope="col">Genre</th>
        <th scope="col">Director</th>
        <th scope="col">Writer</th>
        <th scope="col">Actors</th>
        <th scope="col">Plot</th>
        <th scope="col">Language</th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">Awards</th>
        <th scope="col">imdbRating</th>
        <th scope="col">imdbVotes</th>
        <th scope="col">imdbID</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">BoxOffice</th>
        <th scope="col">Production</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>`;

    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=683c6fd6&t=${name}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.Response == "False") {
        alert(data.Error);
      }else {
            addToTable2(element.Title, element.Year, element.Rated, element.Released,
                element.Genre, element.Director, element.Writer, element.Actors, 
                element.Plot, element.Language, element.Country, element.Awards,
                element.imdbRating, element.imdbVotes, element.imdbID, element.Type,
                element.BoxOffice, element.Production, element.Poster); 
      }
    });
}
```

En el botón <kbd>click here</kbd> de la función *addToTable* hay un *onClick* que llama a *moreInfo*, sin embargo cuando le doy click me tira el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Evidentemente me esta faltando un paréntesis pero no puedo encontrar donde. El VSCode tampoco me encuentra ningún error de syntaxis...

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 1):

Si el parámetro de la función es una cadena, debería estar encerrado entre comillas para evitar dos posibles errores; se expone el error y ejemplo de cómo queda la función:

1. Variable no definida cuando el título es una sola palabra: `moreInfo(Película)`. Seguramente no está declarada una variable para cada título
2. Error actual de sintaxis cuando el título es más de una palabra: `moreInfo(Otra Película)`. En caso de ser variables, se requiere que estén separadas por comas

En fin, no se trata de variables, sino de cadenas.

```
table.innerHTML += `
    <tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td><a href="${poster}">${title}</a></td>
        <td>${id}</td>
        <td style="text-transform: capitalize">${type}</td>
        <td>${year}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="moreInfo('${title}')">Click Here</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>`;
```